# Can we distribute Enterprise ios app through Apple Business manager?

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise, app-distribution, apple-business-manager

I have gone through this [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569042/1635315). I am confused between B2B apps and enterprise apps. Does both are same? I am distributing my enterprise app using `https(itms-services) link` to other users.

So, how to do this with Apple Business manager? Does Apple Business manage has any store like `AppStore` where we have to upload the IPA file or anything else that I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise apps are signed using an enterprise program key and can be distributed directly to that enterprise's devices.  There is no Apple review of enterprise apps.

B2B apps are submitted to App Store Connect using a corporate or company developer program membership. They are reviewed by Apple. They are ether made available for specific Apple IDs to "purchase" (they can be free, with payment made directly to the developer) using the Volume Purchase Program.

Apple Business Manager provides a portal where organisations can:

- Perform Volume Purchase Program purchases (which may be regular App Store apps or B2B apps)
- Enrol devices in the Apple Device Enrolment program to force association with an MDM "out of box".

Apple Business Manager is not involved in actually distributing apps.

An MDM can be used to distribute both Enterprise and B2B apps.